# Elastic search filter histogram based on different data values

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, summary

I am from a mass communication background. Where I send a message to the end user and capture all subsequent events from the end user. I send a message to the end user, on which I receive message delivery information like process, sent, delivered, opened, read, clicked, etc.

***This procedure is used in the following steps:***

1. Send message
2. Receive sent event
3. Receive delivery events
4. Receive an open event
5. Receive a Read event
6. Receive a clicked event (in the case of links in the message and the user clicking on them).

I have added some extra information. When a user opens a message, I am capturing their user agent details, like if the user opens a message from an iOS device, I am setting the user agent as 9808, and in the case of an Android device, I am setting multiple values like 1012, 1013, and 1023 as per the Android device type or handset.

Based on the scenario described above, I generate a summary in which I calculate the total number of requests and their statistics. Like

1. total requests sent
2. total messages delivered
3. total requests opened
4. total messages clicked
5. open type and so on.

I have given a filter based on which the end user can filter the summary. Filter like

1. total sent
2. total open
3. open type i.e., iOS open, or user open

I hope so. Until now, you have identified my basic use case. Now let's talk about data management and how I am managing all this information in Elasticsearch.

So basic document fields and mapping are like below:

Data document:

```json
{
    "took": 12,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 38,
        "successful": 38,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 0.0,
        "hits": [{
            "_index": "sample-202304",
            "_type": "logs",
            "_id": "16825338034249531",
            "_score": 0.0,
            "_source": {
                "clientid": 61448,
                "dsndate": "2023-04-27 12:15:29",
                "subject": "You've been added to a group!",
                "dtime": "2023-04-27 12:15:29",
                "latency": -1,
                "adate": 20230427,
                "itime": "2023-04-27 12:15:30",
                "inj_type": "WHATSAPP",
                "gtime": "2023-04-27 12:15:30",
                "counts_opens": 2,
                "segment_type": 3,
                "msize": 15994,
                "ptime": "2023-04-27 12:15:28",
                "timestamp": 1682585036,
                "atime": "2023-04-27 12:15:30",
                "rdom": "gmail.com",
                "ip": "172.253.115.27",
                "message_id": "",
                "rcpt_email": "sample@gmail.com",
                "fdom": "sample.com",
                "misc1": "",
                "counts_clicks": 0,
                "opens": [{
                        "ip": "103.28.116.12",
                        "useragent": 9808,
                        "time": "2023-04-27 13:02:03"
                    },
                    {
                        "ip": "173.219.224.46",
                        "useragent": 2812,
                        "time": "2023-04-27 15:44:09"
                    },
                    {
                        "ip": "172.219.224.46",
                        "useragent": 2812,
                        "time": "2023-04-27 15:44:09"
                    }
                ],
                "udate": "2023-04-27 15:44:09",
                "fromaddress": "fantasysports@sample.com",
                "custom_data": "",
                "remarks": "173.253.115.27 - 250 2.0.0 OK e9-20020a0562140d8900b005771786395bsi11489394qve.154 - gsmtp (in reply to EOD command)",
                "status": 2
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

In the above sample JSON, I am managing all the basic information about a particular message. I so like that I have plenty of documents with the same data structure but different attributes.

I want to filter all documents based on filter type.

If the end user selects the open type, which is equivalent to machine open, then it should be counted as machine open. for which the filter value must be open. useragent = 9808

If the end user selects the open type, which is equivalent to user open, then it should get counted as a user open. for which the filter value must not include openes. useragent = 9808 (i.e all values apart from 9808 or should not contain value 9808 in opens.useragnet array)

**In short, a filter is like**

1. user open = opens. useragent field should not contain the value 9808.
2. machine open = opens.useragent Apart from 9808, the useragent field should contain any other value.

In the above elasticsearch document, the open field contained a set of multiple events, like two times a user opened and one time a machine opened. In this case, it should be summarised as user-open as it has user-open values and vice versa.

if it contains only 9808 then it should consider as a machine open

Currently, I am running the below query, by which I am getting a date-wise summary of total iPhone opens, which is not correct as unique IOS opens. Because the useragent field contains user open values too,

```json
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/index-202305,index-202304,index-202303,index-202302/_search?from=0&size=0&pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "adate": {
              "gte": "20230427",
              "lte": "20230427"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "clientid": "61448"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "status"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "msize"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "adate"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "daywise_summary": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "adate",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "mailwise": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "status",
            "size": 100000
          }
        },
        "open": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "counts_opens"
          }
        },
        "click": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "counts_clicks"
          }
        },
        "msize": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "msize"
          }
        },
        "iphone_bot_opens": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "opens.useragent": "9808"
            }
          }
        },
        "iphone_bot_clicks": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "clicks.useragent": "9808"
            }
          }
        },
        "amp_clicks": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "clicks.is_amp": 1
            }
          }
        },
        "amp_opens": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "opens.is_amp": 1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

From the above query, I am getting the below output

```json
{
  "took" : 4592,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 38,
    "successful" : 38,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "daywise_summary" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key_as_string" : "20230427",
          "key" : 1682553600000,
          "doc_count" : 3024404,
          "iphone_bot_opens" : {
            "doc_count" : 571625
          },
          "mailwise" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : 1,
                "doc_count" : 2067057
              },
              {
                "key" : 2,
                "doc_count" : 929159
              },
              {
                "key" : 9,
                "doc_count" : 14366
              },
              {
                "key" : 6,
                "doc_count" : 11136
              },
              {
                "key" : 4,
                "doc_count" : 1943
              },
              {
                "key" : 10,
                "doc_count" : 707
              },
              {
                "key" : 8,
                "doc_count" : 22
              },
              {
                "key" : 7,
                "doc_count" : 14
              }
            ]
          },
          "amp_opens" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          "amp_clicks" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          "msize" : {
            "value" : 4.4637554424E10
          },
          "iphone_bot_clicks" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          },
          "click" : {
            "value" : 2025.0
          },
          "open" : {
            "value" : 1212205.0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Please suggest the proper query where I can distinguish end-to-end segregation of unique machine open and unique user open with a date summary.